# Show that the set with $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ with $\mod 6$ arithematic is not a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

I cannot understand what is the logic should i use to do this.Is it multiplicative identity,multiplicative inverse or any other thing

Answer (score 1):

It is a commutative ring, so closedness, distribution and multiplicative identity are all there. The multiplicative identity is $1$.

However, you cannot invert $2$. Try it. Multiply it by any number in the ring, and you will see that none of the six multiplications lead to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

What would the multiplicative identity have to be? Do all non-zero residues have multiplicative inverses with respect to this multiplicative identity?